# jquery append data to select box

Tags: jquery

I am making a ajax call to return a list of states which looks like:

```
"[["Alabama",1],["Alaska",2],["Arizona",3],["Arkansas",4],["California",5],["Colorado",6],["Connecticut",7],["Delaware",8],["Florida",9],["Georgia",10],["Guam",52],["Hawaii",11],["Idaho",12],["Illinois",13],["Indiana",14],["Iowa",15],["Kansas",16],["Kentucky",17],["Louisiana",18],["Maine",19],["Maryland",20],["Massachusetts",21],["Michigan",22],["Minnesota",23],["Mississippi",24],["Missouri",25],["Montana",26],["Nebraska",27],["Nevada",28],["New Hampshire",29],["New Jersey",30],["New Mexico",31],["New York",32],["North Carolina",33],["North Dakota",34],["Northern Mariana Islands",57],["Ohio",35],["Oklahoma",36],["Oregon",37],["Pennsylvania",38],["Philippine Islands",56],["Puerto Rico",53],["Rhode Island",39],["South Carolina",40],["South Dakota",41],["Tennessee",42],["Texas",43],["Utah",44],["Vermont",45],["Virgin Islands",54],["Virginia",46],["Washington",47],["Washington DC",48],["West Virginia",49],["Wisconsin",50],["Wyoming",51]]"
```

How can I append this to the dropdownbox?
e.g. like this:

```
<option value="2" style="display: block;">Alaska</option>
```

My attempt is failing and the select box is empty apart from the first "Please Select":

Here I am removing all options but the first, and trying to append data:

```
selected_item.closest('.address-table').find('.state_select option:gt(0)').remove().append(data);
```

**EDIT:** some more complete code
so here is the JS function, selected_item is the country selectbox, so I want to pull back all the states or territories for that country:

```
function filterTerritory(selected_item) {
    var country_id =  selected_item.val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/addresses/update_states',
        data: {
            country_id: country_id
        },
        dataType: "script",
        success: ( function (data) {
            selected_item.closest('.address-table').find('.state_select option:gt(0)').remove().append(data);
        })
    });
}
```

my rails controller:

```
  def update_states
     @states= get_states_list(params[:country_id]).pluck(:name, :id)    
     respond_to do |format|
       format.json { render json: @states.as_json }
     end
  end
```

Comment: its the first line in my OP with all the states in it, and values

Comment: Looks invalid data, it is not a valid array.

Comment: Not exactly the solution, but you need to `parse` the data as well? `JSON.parse(data)` and then iterate over it to create `option` which then should be appended to the dropdown

Comment: its coming from a ruby on rails controller action, it should be rendering as json:  render json: @states.as_json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery will not generate option tag from the array or JSON string, instead you need to generate elements either as html string or jQuery object using the array only after that you can append the element other wise the JSON string will be appended.

Also you are trying to append the element to the removed option which will not make any effect, you need to back to the select tag selector and append the generated content.

```js
var data = '[["Alabama",1],["Alaska",2],["Arizona",3],["Arkansas",4],["California",5],["Colorado",6],["Connecticut",7],["Delaware",8],["Florida",9],["Georgia",10],["Guam",52],["Hawaii",11],["Idaho",12],["Illinois",13],["Indiana",14],["Iowa",15],["Kansas",16],["Kentucky",17],["Louisiana",18],["Maine",19],["Maryland",20],["Massachusetts",21],["Michigan",22],["Minnesota",23],["Mississippi",24],["Missouri",25],["Montana",26],["Nebraska",27],["Nevada",28],["New Hampshire",29],["New Jersey",30],["New Mexico",31],["New York",32],["North Carolina",33],["North Dakota",34],["Northern Mariana Islands",57],["Ohio",35],["Oklahoma",36],["Oregon",37],["Pennsylvania",38],["Philippine Islands",56],["Puerto Rico",53],["Rhode Island",39],["South Carolina",40],["South Dakota",41],["Tennessee",42],["Texas",43],["Utah",44],["Vermont",45],["Virgin Islands",54],["Virginia",46],["Washington",47],["Washington DC",48],["West Virginia",49],["Wisconsin",50],["Wyoming",51]]';

$('#select') // get select
  .find('option:gt(0)') // find options to remove
  .remove() // remove the options
  .end() // back to the previous selector
  .append(
    JSON.parse(data) // parse the json 
    .map(function(v) { // generate jQuery object array to append
      return $('<option>', { // create option using array element
        text: v[0], // set text
        value: v[1] // set value
      });
    }));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option value="a" style="display: block;">aaaa</option>
  <option value="a" style="display: block;">aaaa</option>
  <option value="a" style="display: block;">aaaa</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I like the way you use `map` and `reduce` in most of your answers. But here I am confused as to how the `text` and `value` is interpreted.

Comment: @SandeepNayak : `return $('<option>', { // create option using array element
      text: v[0], // set text
      value: v[1] // set value
    });`

Comment: I'm getting:  Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function

Comment: @user3437721 :  in case it's a string then you need to parse it

Comment: what do you mean parse it, what should I parse?  Thanks

Comment: great answer. I have a question which you dont have to answerf fully, but I am calling this on a page load as a country is preselected with USA.  but how can I preserve the state selected on a postback, I dont want to filter again if they already selected something

Comment: @user3437721 : `return $('<option>', {
        text: v[0], 
        value: v[1],
        selected: v[0]=='state'
      });`  add selected attribute while creating `option` tag

Answer (score 0):

You can't just `append` your data in that format and expect `jQuery` to know to create `option` elements. First, use `JSON.parse(data)` to get your data in JSON form, and use `.each()` to create `option` element.

Answer (score 0):

You should first parse JSON with `JSON.parse()` and then append to `select`

```js
var data = '[["Alabama",1],["Alaska",2],["Arizona",3],["Arkansas",4],["California",5],["Colorado",6],["Connecticut",7],["Delaware",8],["Florida",9],["Georgia",10],["Guam",52],["Hawaii",11],["Idaho",12],["Illinois",13],["Indiana",14],["Iowa",15],["Kansas",16],["Kentucky",17],["Louisiana",18],["Maine",19],["Maryland",20],["Massachusetts",21],["Michigan",22],["Minnesota",23],["Mississippi",24],["Missouri",25],["Montana",26],["Nebraska",27],["Nevada",28],["New Hampshire",29],["New Jersey",30],["New Mexico",31],["New York",32],["North Carolina",33],["North Dakota",34],["Northern Mariana Islands",57],["Ohio",35],["Oklahoma",36],["Oregon",37],["Pennsylvania",38],["Philippine Islands",56],["Puerto Rico",53],["Rhode Island",39],["South Carolina",40],["South Dakota",41],["Tennessee",42],["Texas",43],["Utah",44],["Vermont",45],["Virgin Islands",54],["Virginia",46],["Washington",47],["Washington DC",48],["West Virginia",49],["Wisconsin",50],["Wyoming",51]]';
var options = '';

JSON.parse(data).forEach(function(e) {
  options += '<option value="'+e[1]+'" style="display: block;">'+e[0]+'</option>';
})

$('#state_select').empty().append(options);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="state_select">
  <option value="a">A</option>
</select>
```

Comment: my code doesnt seem to like the rocket =>, says expression expected?

Answer (score 0):

you can do follow:(like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ananis/hwhp2nug/2/)

```
var out='';
for(i in data){
    out+="<option value="+data[i][1]+">"+data[i][0]+"</option>";
}
$('select').append(out)
```